# Flagging a comment in documentation

Tags: support, documentation, comment-flags, documentation-discussion

How do I flag a comment in the Documentation?

After I made a comment on a topic, the OP commented back with a personal attack, and I don't see a way to flag it as not constructive.

Edit: do I need to contact staff about this? I don't like being lied about, even if only in a comment.

Comment: If it's urgent, you can probably flag one of your answers, use the "needs moderator attention" reason, and provide the link to the Documentation page containing that comment and an explanation of the problem. I'm *assuming* moderators can delete comments from Documentation, but I'm not sure. Either way, this may need to turn into a [feature-request].

Comment: Could you provide a link to where this happened? I'm really curious to see what such a comment looks like, since the discussion stuff is all pretty new. I haven't seen a case of something like this before, and I can't seem to track back through your Documentation history to find it. Like Cody, I'm not sure what our capabilities are in this regard, and it might provide a good example for expanding moderation powers here.

Comment: @BradLarson Yes, I cant find it either in my profile; had to look it up through the Documentation menu structure. But here it is, the [example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/xhtml/9045/getting-started-with-xhtml/28091/xhtml5-and-boolean-attributes) and the [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/td/e/9045/28091). (I'm also not sure how to display both the example and the discussion about the example on one page; that might require some looking into.)

Comment: @MrLister - OK, it does look like moderators have the ability to edit and delete Documentation comments, like we can with comments on the main site. No flagging options directly on there, but a link to a comment in a custom flag on the main site should let us act on these currently. The fact that we can't see comments from someone's profile is concerning, and may be worth a feature request by itself.

Comment: OK, so what am I supposed to do now? Flag one of my own comments? Or does the fact that you've seen the offending comment and not removed it mean that it would be declined?

Comment: For the moment, feel free to use the "contact us" form at the bottom of the page to report spam and rudeness. In the meantime, I've edit the comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### We're preparing proper flagging on Documentation

Initially, Documentation had regular flags for content. As we tinkered with the feature it morphed into Improvement Requests. Unfortunately, that's left a few holes:

1. Since improvement requests themselves are publicly visible inputs, they might benefit from flags.
2. As we added in comments and other forms of meta discussion, those need flags too.
3. While easy edits and rigorous review avoid the worst forms of abuse, there are still situations that might require moderator powers to address.

To be fair, we've known about these problems. We've just avoided pushing them to moderators while building the system. That's not going to cut it anymore.

As a preview, we are planning on making Documentation flags work a lot like flags in Q&A. There will be a few differences, but the system ought to be fairly intuitive for Stack Overflow users. Several spam and offensive flags (6 initially) will cause automatic removal of flagged content. Moderators will see these flags in the moderator dashboard and will be able handle them as usual.

Comment: Thank you. Since you edited the comment, my immediate problem is solved, so that's all for now. Thanks again.