# How do we stop new users from using the Discussion feature to ask questions?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-discussion

I just encountered [this "discussion"](//stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/td/g/898/40) in Getting started with Apache Maven:

> #### can't install Maven
>
> helo everyone, i have just delete eclipe, and install another version, but when i wantet to instal maven,

It's obvious that this doesn't belong in the discussions section—if anything, it's a question, and a terrible, off-topic, delete-worthy question at that.

I can't quite find the original comment, but let me quote one of my favorite [comments from Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336273/):

> If there is a textbox on The Internet, someone will eventually type a programming question in it.

We're definitely going to get more of these—what should we do to stop them? At the moment, there's very little that I can do about it.

I've given my own thoughts below, but I'd like to see if anyone else has more ideas.

Comment: They really should implement a flagging mechanism for spam/rude/abusive as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver that's a great idea! Almost as if it should be an answer…

Comment: raise entry barrier of course.

Comment: @KevinB See my comment above.

Comment: What does Wikipedia do to keep Q&A out of talk pages?

Comment: @NathanOliver - ["As a preview, we are planning on making Documentation flags work a lot like flags in Q&A."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343835/19679)

Comment: @BradLarson Awesome.  Thanks.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Whatever they're doing, it's really effective - I couldn't find a revision of any talk page with a help request. They do have a "this is not a forum" banner though (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:IOS_jailbreaking)). I would assume changes that violate the guidelines are simply undone, which, on talk pages, can be done by anyone if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

Like NathanOliver mentioned [in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344353/how-do-we-stop-new-users-from-using-the-discussion-feature-to-ask-questions#comment450522_344353), I'd like to see the flag system from comments brought over.

The standard flags would likely work, although an additional "is a question" might be more obvious than "not constructive" even if both are technically correct.

If a discussion gets a certain number of flags, it is automatically deleted.

Additionally, since tag badges seem to be very applicable to Documentation, allow users with gold badges in the associated tag to unilaterally remove discussions. Perhaps a weighting system could be used such that flags from bronze and silver tag badge holders each have more weight.

Comment: It's the silver ones that give you god-powers in your tag.

Answer (score 2):

My idea is: I think that we should introduce the closure/deletion system to discussions.

We would likely need to make some tweaks, such as:

- Some changes to the available close reasons:

  - Get rid of Too Broad and Primarily Opinion-Based.
  - Replace Off-Topic with something like "irrelevant".
- Expand the mighty Mjölnr to all close reasons, and let silver tag badge holders (aka pretty-much-a-moderator in relevant Documentation tags) wield it.
- Silver tag badge holders can cast (singular) delete votes, regardless of reputation.
- Instead of score, we could scale required votes by, for example, the number of users participating and the length.

Comment: They could extend the dismiss votes from requests to discussions in general. That's basically close voting in docs anyway.

Comment: So, is this just about discussions? Because I think the better analog is comments, in which case we should just be able to flag them as "not a discussion", and if there are enough of those flags, it gets deleted. Implementing the whole queue/voting system seems a bit heavy handed for something as hidden as discussions.

Comment: Or just trust people with tag badges to know what they are doing and give them a "nuke" button...

Comment: Aren't "off-topic" and "irrelevant" two words for the same thing?

Comment: @TinyGiant in plain English, yes. On Stack Exchange Q&A, no; off-topic is really just a (confusing, unhelpful) catch-all term for "violates a site-specific rule", and frequently doesn't *really* mean off-topic at all in the plain English sense. Picking a different plain-English-synonym of "off-topic" to avoid confusion with the weird Stack Exchange definition of "off-topic" thus seems reasonable.

Comment: @Mark I'm fairly certain that off-topic _is_ directly related to topical it on Stack Overflow. I don't see why you would think otherwise.

Comment: @TinyGiant because the "off-topic" reasons clearly describe things that have nothing to do with topicality. Whether a bug that's being asked about is caused by a simple typo plainly has nothing to do with whether the question is *related to programming*, and as such calling such a question "off-topic" is perverse... but that's how the close reason is classified.

Comment: Scope is definitely part of topicality. The topicality of Stack Overflow is not just _programming_. It's much narrower than that. @Mark

Comment: @TinyGiant meh. We evidently have different definitions of what a 'topic' is - but I don't think that arguing over who has the more correct definition is a worthwhile use of time for either of us. :)

Comment: [Whaddaya mean it ain't a worthwhile use of our time?](https://xkcd.com/386/) @Mark