# How to handle plagiarized documentation edit that is still approved

Tags: discussion, documentation, review-queues, plagiarism

Reviewing [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/129230) I found that a lot of it is a verbatim copying of [the "Setting up Studio" Appcelerator docs page](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Setting_up_Studio). Compare e.g. the section:

> To install and run Studio on OS X using the GUI:
>
> 1. Launch the Studio DMG you downloaded.
> 2. Double-click the PKG file in the dialog.

and following. As far as I can see there is no attribution and thus this is obviously plagiarism. I rejected giving the link and nonetheless two of the three subsequent reviewers approved the edit such that it is now approved in total.

I feel that ignoring this is not an option and as I am not sure what the proper reaction would be. Should I just submit a rollback request or should I somehow flag this?

Comment: Bans, copious amounts of them for reviewers. Rollbacks, too.

Comment: I don't know if it changed, but flags doesn't do in documentation what it does on main.

Comment: I just realized that as well @Braiam ... why on earth is that?

Comment: @Bart Because naturally it's impossible for anyone to do anything problematic in documentation.

Comment: Ok so rolling back is more or less the only thing I can do?

Comment: There is no more valid Documentation edit. Some of them are approved mainly because it's too long to explain why it's incorrect.

Comment: <head pointing meme>Don't have to  handle flags if they can't flag</head pointing meme> @Servy

Comment: Please flag these. 

As Braiam pointed out, moderators are more than happy to ban the reviewers and also strictly warn the users who plagiarize. Do rollback the plagiarized changes, this might send out a warning to the user, before the moderators handle your flag. 


That said, [The devs are planning to implement **proper flagging mechanism for docs**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343835/4099593).

Comment: @Bart why for art thou answer deleted?

Comment: @TinyGiant Because there really isn't a proper mechanism for flagging where I assumed there would be.

Comment: Until proper flagging is implemented in Documentation, we have to go to the reviewer's profile page. Then use a custom mod flag on one of their posts, with a link to the Documentation item. (Multiple examples of bad reviewing are preferred. Then the moderator can see that the reviewer did not just mis-click or had a momentary lapse of judgment).